# Одна строка много колонок inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется следующая структура таблиц.

```
**Products:**
  -id
  -title
  -price
**Equipments**
  -id
  -title
**Eqvalues**
  -id
  -equipment_id
  -value
**Equipment_product_value**
  -id
  -product_id
  -equipment_id
  -value_id
```

Хочу вывести данные в формате.

```
|products.title|products.price|equipments.title-1|eqvalues.value-1|equipments.title-N|eqvalues.value-N
```

Простыми словами, у товара есть характеристики (equipments) и значения этих характеристик (values) которые нужно вывести. Возможно ли так сделать. Моя часть реализации:

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.status, products.price, products.info, 
                         product_photo.filename, equipments.title AS etitle, values.value
                 FROM products
                 INNER JOIN product_photo ON products.id = product_photo.product_id 
                 INNER JOIN equipment_product ON products.id = equipment_product.product_id 
                 INNER JOIN equipments ON equipment_product.equipment_id = equipments.id
                 INNER JOIN `values` ON equipment_product.value_id = values.id
                 GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: Это называется PIVOT.

Comment: в вопросе одни таблицы, в запросе другие. И что конкретно у вас не работает? Что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже у вас `MySQL`.

В общем случае нельзя вывести в несколько столбцов каждое свойств. Вы ведь не знаете изначально сколько всего может быть строк.

Зато можно вывести все свойства товара в одном столбце с разделителем |, с помощью функции `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.status, products.price, products.info, 
                         product_photo.filename, 
                         GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
                            CONCAT(equipments.title, '|', values.value) 
                            ORDER BY equipments.title 
                            SEPARATOR '|'
                        ) AS prodInfo
                 FROM products
                 INNER JOIN product_photo ON products.id = product_photo.product_id 
                 INNER JOIN equipment_product ON products.id = equipment_product.product_id 
                 INNER JOIN equipments ON equipment_product.equipment_id = equipments.id
                 INNER JOIN `values` ON equipment_product.value_id = values.id
                 GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: Да mysql. Изначально тоже думал, использовать GROUP_CONCAT, только на два столбца.В принципи такой вариант подходит. PHP поправит :)

Comment: только как избавится от дублей, а то по 2 раза каждая запись.

Comment: @depredator, добавить DISTINCT, в ответе добавил. Однако странно, что у вас дубли, по идее при такой структуре не должно быть, какого-то условия возможно не хватает.

Comment: да  DISTINCT - все исправил.